# ArcGIS Server and Microsoft SQL Server database connection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

I have an ArcGIS Server and I need to register a Microsoft SQL Server database as a data storage. When I connect to database directly from ArcMap everything is fine, but when i'm trying to register a database I have a message, that 'connection properties lost parameter or it cannot be defined. Trying to connect with older version of sql server client, that is not supported' (I have a localized version). Where can be a problem? I connect to SQL Server DB using domain authorization.

Comment: This might be super hard to troubleshoot. Any chance you could talk to your Esri Tech Support rep?

Comment: The standard answer from ETS is - this is not a common case, you may purchase our specialist's time to resolve this problem.

Comment: There's missing information from this question. Please [Edit] the question to contain the exact releases of ArcGIS, SQL Server, and the Microsoft client libraries in use (on both ArcMap and AGS hosts), whether the AGS host is on the domain, and the exact registration procedure. It sounds like you have an unsupported environment.

Comment: ok, here is the config: ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.1, ArcGis Server Enterprise 10.5.1, SQL Server base ver. 2014. MS Sql native client ver.13. I have tried to connect using db admin account instead of domain auth. and got the same result. I use the standard procedure via catalog in ArcMap: Server properties - data storage - import data storage connection - server connection to db - as publisher